# Radio button text issue in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton3" runat="server" Text="Test" />
```

Getting radio button text in the next line (below the radio button) and facing table alignment issues in default.aspx, but the same code works fine with other web form pages.

How to fix this?

Comment: Might be a width issue with your table and td.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `display: block;` to display RadioButton's text in next line.

*Please make sure other CSS rules are not overriding this.*

[image]

```
<style type="text/css">
    .radiobutton label { display: block; }
</style>

<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton3" runat="server" Text="Test" 
   CssClass="radiobutton" />
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" Text="Test" 
   CssClass="radiobutton" />
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" runat="server" Text="Test" 
   CssClass="radiobutton" />
```

Comment: .radiobutton label { display:inline-block ; } helped me to fix the problem. Thanks a lot.